# How to show null data when data does not exist in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I am joining two tables, and i want to show data when id of both is equal. And when id is not equal so show nothing, but it is showing everything.

This is my Controller

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
class profile extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
         $this->load->model("profile_model");
         $data['profile_records']=$this->profile_model->getAllRecords();

    }

}

?>
```

This is my Model

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
class profile_model extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
}

    function getAllRecords()
    {


        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('ads AS A');// I use aliasing make things joins easier
        $this->db->join('membership AS C', 'C.id = A.ad_id', 'INNER');
        $this->db->where('A.ad_id  = C.ad_fk'); 

             $q = $this->db->get("ads");
            if($q->num_rows() > 0)
            {
               return $q->result();
            }
            return array();
    }
}
?>
```

This is my views

```
<?php




foreach ($profile_records as $profile_rows)
{
?>

<span>


    echo "<span class='title2'>". $profile_rows->ad_timestamp ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
    <?php  echo "<span class='title2'>". $profile_rows->ad_title ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
    <?php  echo "<span class='title'>". $profile_rows->ad_description ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
    <?php  echo "<span class='title2'>". $profile_rows->cat_type ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
    <?php  echo "<span class='title2'>". $profile_rows->ad_name ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
    <?php  echo "<span class='description'>". $profile_rows->ad_phone ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
    <?php  echo "<span class='name'>". $profile_rows->ad_address ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
    <?php  echo "<span class='phone'>". $profile_rows->ad_flag."</span>"."<br/>";?>
    <?php  //echo "<span class='website'>". $row->address ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
</span>
<hr width="600px" />
<?php }?>
```

How to show null data when data does not exist in database using codeigniter

Comment: Sounds like a MySQL `join` question though i did not understand the actual problem, Can you please include some sample data from the tables you wish to join and the desired result?

Comment: Kindly show us what you are getting the result to help you better as whatever you have attached in comment is not working.

Comment: @Muhammad, please copy the pictures above into your question - those links require GMail authentication, and no-one else can see them.

Answer (score 0):

As far i understand you want to print null if the value is empty? So here is the code.

in your model try to put this code instead

```
$q = $this->db->get("ads");
        if($q->num_rows() > 0)
        {
           return $q->result();
        }
        return false;
```

and in your view

```
if(!$profile_records)
{
    //the value is null
   echo "The value is null";
}
else
{
    foreach ($profile_records as $profile_rows)
    {
    ?>

       <span>

         echo "<span class='title2'>". $profile_rows->ad_timestamp ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
         <?php  echo "<span class='title2'>". $profile_rows->ad_title ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
         <?php  echo "<span class='title'>". $profile_rows->ad_description ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
         <?php  echo "<span class='title2'>". $profile_rows->cat_type ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
         <?php  echo "<span class='title2'>". $profile_rows->ad_name ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
         <?php  echo "<span class='description'>". $profile_rows->ad_phone ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
         <?php  echo "<span class='name'>". $profile_rows->ad_address ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
         <?php  echo "<span class='phone'>". $profile_rows->ad_flag."</span>"."<br/>";?>
         <?php  //echo "<span class='website'>". $row->address ."</span>"."<br/>";?>
     </span>
     <hr width="600px" />
  <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: kindly see my code carefully i am joining two tables. Your code is not working correctly

Comment: i know your joining table, my suggested code in model is correct. Where is the error

Comment: my condition is that when both id is equal so show data, or when id is not equal or not exist so show nothing, but your code printing everything which is available in my db

Comment: because you remove this code in your model,  $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('ads AS A');// I use aliasing make things joins easier
        $this->db->join('membership AS C', 'C.id = A.ad_id', 'INNER');
        $this->db->where('A.ad_id  = C.ad_fk'); after that code insert the code that i suggested

Comment: try to use that statement in your sql to determine what the result needed to show

Comment: Ok i will try to catch you later.